# Kofax Java wrapper on Linux

Tags: java, .net, linux, windows, kofax

Currently I am using .net application and kofax scan.exe to virtually scan my documents into kofax, but i want to switch from .net to java (Linux) and still achieve the virtual scan functionality in kofax.

Anyone has idea if kofax has any API or Java wrapper ?

Comment: Not sure which Kofax product you are referring to. Scan.exe is part of Kofax Capture (KC) - is your goal to import electronic documents such as TIFF files or PDFs into KC?

Comment: yes, My goal is to import Digital Document into KC as TIFF .

Answer (score 1):

While running Kofax Capture (KC) entirely on Linux might be possible using Wine or similar frameworks, I would advise against it (KC is highly customizable, so what will happen to OCX controls written in .NET or oldschool COM, et cetera - lots of rabbit holes). Run KC itself on a Windows machine, and if you have to be on *nix only, run it in a container (e.g. Docker).

Alternatively, KC may already run on a dedicated server, and you're simply trying to get documents imported using your *nix machine - if that's the case, here are your options:

1. Use [Kofax Capture Import Connector](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Capture/Overview-Downloads/Kofax_Import_Connector_Overview-Downloads). KIC covers a wide variety of channels - File, Email, Fax, and Web Services. For example, you could run KIC on your server, and then use its web service interface to import files.
2. Use oldschool Kofax XML Import. Install ACXMLAI.exe on your KC machine, let it import from a file server. Move (or create) XML and TIFF files in your Java app, and store them on said server, e.g. using SMB. You will need to create an XML file, [here's how](https://knowledge.kofax.com/Capture/00_Product_Documentation__User_Guides/00_Kofax_Capture_Product_Documentation_Master/04_Kofax_Capture_90_Product_Documentation/01_All_Kofax_Capture_90_Product_Documentation_compressed). While the docs are for KC9, this interface really hasn't changed much.

Answer (score 0):

Writing as answer since I cant comment yet. I would not advise to use the AXCMLAI.exe that @Wolfgang Radl mentioned.

It is marked as obsolete, and may be removed in a next future version.

KIC is more to use in this case, but If you bought KC before the license bundle it might be to expensive.

I would not recommend the migration of KC to a linux environment unless you want to do extensive testing.

Be aware their support will probably dismiss any ticket you may have due to not having a prerequisite server.